# Can you count on .finalize() to be called?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I was attempting to instrument some of my Java code to ensure objects were being garbage collected correctly, and I found that surprisingly it wasn't being called as often as I expected.

I am now wondering if this is because of faulty instrumentation or an actual memory leak I need to solve.  the VisualVM profiler seems to indicate the former.

The situation of concern is that I have a thread which handles requests and inside the request creates thousands of temporary objects.  Sometimes, the socket this thread writes to is unexpectedly closed and the thread hits an exception and dies.

When the Thread dies, it doesn't seem like .finalize() is ever called on those objects.  Is this a reason to not trust my instrumentation?

Comment: Do you have a simple, self-contained example that shows this behaviour?

Comment: @aix: yes, of course, he's got a situation involving thousands of objects, network access and an unexpected socket closing.  He doesn't know where the issue comes from which, btw, is **precisely** why he comes here asking his question... Yet he should trivially write a self-contained example reproducing the issue.  Honestly this "SSCCE agenda", which originated in *comp.lang.java* on Usenet (and was already pushed there by the very same people pushing it here on SO), is getting tiring...  I mean, seriously, have you *read* the question?  What about *you* write a SSCCE reproducing this?

Comment: @CedricMartin: Calm down. I think it was a reasonable question to ask. If the answer is no, the answer is no. There's no reason to get so worked up about nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  There is no guarantee that it will be called.  However, it is usually called.  It may be that you are not properly releasing your objects, or the garbage collector has not run, or the finalizer thread is waiting for a good time to run.

You can read about it in the [Finalization of Class Instances](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.6) portion of the language spec.

Answer (score 4):

Finalize() is not the solution. You cannot know when finalizer will be called if any. If your problem is exception use `try/catch/finally` blocks and close/clean all stuff you want to close in finally block. This guarantees that everything will be cleaned in both cases: the logic terminated normally or exception was thrown.

Answer (score 1):

According to all I read on Java basics you should **never** rely on finalize to be run. finalize() is **not a destructor** you may know from other languages.

From java.lang.Object javadoc:

```
The Java programming language does not guarantee which thread will invoke the finalize method for any given object.
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()

The way I see things, the dreaded finalize should and is only used if you include some native code in your app. But even then be sure not to rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion seems to be whether there is a memory leak or not. You are trying to establish this by looking at whether `finalize()` was called or not. If that is so then it's the not the correct to check whether there is a memory leak or not.

Just so we're clear, in Java, [memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470651/creating-a-memory-leak-with-java) mostly mean hidden references to objects you don't need.

Purpose of `finalize()` to give an opportunity to developer to clean up his own mess (connections, streams, ...). Memory is supposed to be JVM's mess/headache and cleaned up by GC.

So in short, fact that "*GC guarantees to call `finalize()` before is frees memory*", shouldn't be interpreted as "*if `finalize()` is not called there is a memory leak*". It could simply be that that object is not ***yet*** garbage collected.

If you're looking to find memory leak use a tool. See options:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=find+java+memory+leak
- [How to find a Java Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119/how-to-find-a-java-memory-leak)
- [Can there be memory leak in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987357/can-there-be-memory-leak-in-java)